Request for migration to Math SE
How can I ask for request for migration to Math SE?  I think my question is more related to the mathematics of a theorem than the exact cryptographic system or implementation of. 

Do you mean your own question at http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/44254/ ? If that’s the one, just leave a "yes" as a comment here and I’ll migrate it within the blink of an eye.

Yes. That is the one thank you.

Generally, you can always use a "flag – for moderator attention" and ask for migration.



